# Spring MVC attach file to message

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to attach a file to a message via Spring mvc(the path of this file is registred in the Database).

How can I do that?

Comment: Spring E-mail? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html

Comment: yes an email,I have the email body in the database and I have the path of the attached file, so I want to send the email with the attached file to a group of users

Comment: I use the following code when I chose the file to attach via the jsp  MultipartFile attachedFile = messageDto.getFile();
    try {
             InputStream inputStream = null;
             OutputStream outputStream = null;
             if (attachedFile.getSize() > 0) {
                    inputStream = attachedFile.getInputStream();            
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation+"/static/docs/emailAttachFiles/"+attachedFile.getOriginalFilename());
                    int readBytes = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];

Comment: while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
         outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
   }
  outputStream.close();
  inputStream.close();
 }
 messageDto.setFilePath(server+"/static/docs/emailAttachFiles/"+attachedFile.getOriginalFilename());
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
} but my problem is if I know the path of the file on the server, how can I build the file and attach to an email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will help: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html#mail-javamail-mime-attachments